# How to align items with different heights?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm not sure how better to describe it, so:
I have a grid for 12 columns. (2 identical icons and 2 texts with different heights) per 6 columns. Is there any way to align icons by center and texts by the same height?  I'm able to align icons but texts are always on different heights.

```css
  .benefits .benefits_item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 35px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.benefits .benefits_item .benefits_round {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 25px;
  width: 116px;
  height: 116px;
  background: #1EACC7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.benefits .benefits_item .benefits_descr {
  width: 370px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #202020;
}

.benefits .benefits_item .benefits_descr span {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #1EACC7;
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="benefits_item">
      <div class="benefits_round"><img src="" alt="1" class="benefits_icon"></div>
      <div class="benefits_descr"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame</span><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec arcu ligula, lacinia vel fermentum elementum</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="benefits_item">
      <div class="benefits_round"><img src="" alt="2" class="benefits_icon"></div>
      <div class="benefits_descr"><span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec arcu ligula, lacinia vel fermentum elementum, malesuada vel ante. Donec ut odio augue. Integer a aliquet quam. Aenean ut enim ullamcorper, feugiat neque ac,
        pretium augue.</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the mock-up or rough sketch of the exact layout? Maybe even a screenshot/link of an existing example to help understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Could you make your snippet work? (ie include bootstrap so we see the columnal layout). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **align-items-center** to `<div class="row">` -- Bootstrap's rows use `display: flex` so you can use other flex utility classes on the row

```css
:root {
  --color: #1EACC7;
  --iconSize: 6rem;
}

.benefits_round {
  height: var( --iconSize );
  max-width: var( --iconSize ); min-width: var( --iconSize );
  background-color: var( --color );
}

.benefits_descr span { color: var( --color ) }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-md">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="benefits_round rounded-circle me-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <img src="" alt="1">
        </div>
        <div class="benefits_descr fw-light">
          <span class="fs-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame</span>
          <br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec arcu ligula, lacinia vel fermentum elementum
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="benefits_round rounded-circle me-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <img src="" alt="2">
        </div>
        <div class="benefits_descr fw-light">
          <span class="fs-5">Lorem ipsum</span>
          <br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec arcu ligula, lacinia vel fermentum elementum, malesuada vel ante. Donec ut odio augue. Integer a aliquet quam. Aenean ut enim ullamcorper, feugiat neque ac, pretium augue.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```